# How to make the "advanced pie chart" in ngx charts in angular2 vertically?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, charts, ngx-charts

i'm new in angular js I used to customize the style in css easily but here I couldn't

i'm using ngx-charts "advanced pie chart" and I need to make the results vertically how can I do this ?

for example the attachment here
[image]

shows the results horizontally
but my div has small width and large height so I need to move the results to be below the circle chart.

Thank you.

Comment: I have a question about display of the advanced-pie-chart on ipad. are the chart values is Nan ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I had the same problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dmoo.png). In your styles.css (or styles.scss), put this code:

```
.advanced-pie-legend .legend-items-container .legend-items {
  overflow: initial !important;
}
```

[after the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ6D2.png)

for me, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB8vc.png)

Use display variable to control. Add this code in your css style file.

```
.advanced-pie-legend .legend-items-container .legend-items .legend-item {
    display: inherit !important;
}
```

Add if you seem the result area is too big. You can control it at this.

```
.advanced-pie-legend {
    width: 15rem !important;
}
```